# Arithmetic expression as printf arg

Tags: c

I am not able to understand why

```
float x = (4+2%-8);
printf("%f\n", x);
```

prints 6.000000 and

```
printf("%f\n", (4+2%-8));
```

prints 0.000000. Any information will be helpful.
Regards.

Comment: In the absence of a **strong** reason otherwise, prefer `double` over `float` for floating-point objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `(4 + 2 % -8)` produces an integer and you are trying to print a float (and they don't match).

In the first case the integer is converted to `float` (because of the assignment) so later on the `printf` works because the value is in a format `%f` expects.

Try this:

```
printf("%f\n", (4.0 + 2 % -8));
                 ^
```

Comment: how can I cast `(4 + 2 % -8)` to a float?

Comment: @Tapas Bose No need to cast, just add a `.0` like in my answer.

Comment: or like `printf("%f\n", (float)(4+2%-8));`

Comment: @TapasBose If you like that more :-) I generally stay away from casts (because I'm a chicken).

Comment: @Tapas: why `float`? Convert to `double` and avoid two conversions (the first explicitly to `float` with the cast and the 2nd implicitly by the compiler before "sending" the value to the variadic function).

Answer (score 2):

It's because here:

```
float x = (4+2%-8);
```

The `(4+2%-8)` is of type `int` but is converted to `float` because that's the type of `x`. However, here:

```
printf("%f\n", (4+2%-8));
```

No cast is performed so you pass an `int` where it expects a `float` giving you a garbage value. You can fix this with a simple cast:

```
printf("%f\n", (float)(4+2%-8));
```

Comment: why convert to `float`? Convert to `double` and avoid two conversions (the first explicitly to `float` with the cast and the 2nd implicitly by the compiler before "sending" the value to the variadic function).

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet the resulting `int` value is implicitly converted to `float` due to assignment, in the second snippet you are lying to the compiler: you tell it to expect a value of type `double` but "send" a value of type `int` instead.

**Do not lie to the compiler. It will get its revenge.**

Note that the `printf` conversion specifier `"%f"` expects a value of type `double`, but "sending" a `float` is ok because that value is automagically converted to `double` before the function is called.